# How to force websites opened in Google Chrome to light mode on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, dark-mode

After upgrading Chrome to 114.0.5735.90, it now follows the system dark mode. I want to force websites opened in Google Chrome to use light mode while keeping the OS on dark mode. I've tried to disable `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` but not luck, it does nothing.

Comment: You can open and new tab customize chrome button and click on colors and themes and change the theme.    .....    That all the option chrome gives

Comment: Even if I choose a light theme, the websites still follow the system theme.

Comment: I use Light Mode (Windows and Linux) and Chrome works fine on all websites that way.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear, I need to keep using the dark theme on all applications except browsers, Google chrome show web contents on dark mode and I want to force it to light mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently impossible to achieve this easily. `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` only attempts to set `prefers-color-scheme` media option to `dark`, setting it to `false` only means it won't try to enforce it, not that'll try to enforce light theme.

This is suggested as a feature in [Chromium's bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1046660&q=prefers-color-scheme%20light&can=2), which doesn't seem to have much progress - you can bump it with good reasoning why this option should exist.

As a workaround, the best thing you can do is launch dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), then under `Styles` tab click on this icon in top right corner of toolbar: [image: icon] and choose `prefers-colors-scheme: light`. That isn't preserved ofc, though. You can also set this to a shortcut after clicking cog icon (settings) -> `Shortcuts` -> `Toggle CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme`.

Comment: this doesn't work, at least in ubuntu 22.04.2. It still forces the GNOME system-wide preference

Comment: Thanks for the downvote for not being able to read correctly... As I wrote, it's a **feature request that requires inconsistent workarounds**, so ofc it won't work... What do you want to work here when I'm specifically stating it's not widely available and devs aren't implementing it?

Comment: You can attempt to set it in system, but the question isn't accurate in terms of that and different GUIs will have different ways of achieving it. So this answers the question for Linux/Chrome in general.

Answer (score 12):

This fixed the issue for me in Ubuntu jammy (to be called in a terminal):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
```

(*edit*)
To further explain:

The tool `gsettings` allows to inspect and manipulate the configuration of GTK applications (such as Google Chrome).  An entry in the configuration belongs to a schema (here: `org.gnome.desktop.interface`), has a key (here: `color-schema`) and an appropriate value (here, one of: `default`, `prefer-dark`, `prefer-light`).  The setting will affect all applications that consume this configuration entry.

See also: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GSettings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked for me, didn't even have to restart chrome. Thanks!

Comment: this does not work since beginning of July, there seems to be a new update that affects the behavior of `prefer-light` GNOME option

Comment: Can you explain why this works, what this setting means, and what else it might affect?

Comment: @DrewNutter, edited and expanded the answer

Answer (score 1):

`chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` is ***Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents***, not for the browser interface itself.

You can install a Theme from the Chrome Web Store to change the theme back. Something like [**Light Theme for Google Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/light-theme-for-google-ch/macolkedjdbklefnogmlebabkakpcacg?hl=en) or [**Default Light Theme**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/default-light-theme/fplbbklnjmefcncfpmimobgdmhpcjehe?hl=en).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do need to force light mode for Web contents not the interface. I've tried the theme you linked, they do change the interface to light, but the website are still dark.

Comment: wow that great, it's worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

[Dark reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) extension solved this issue for me. Now all apps including chrome on ubuntu are in dark theme, but websites are displayed in original colors. In extension I put it to "off" and now all works fine.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. I tried setting it to off and it had no effect. I tried  setting websites to "light" mode, but they actually remained dark, just slightly less dark.